# Remove Category names on top without CSS

Tags: php, html, wordpress, related-posts

I used WP_Query to get related post in the same category but when showing to html, the category names appear on top of the posts.
How can I remove them by setting parameters to WP_Query and not using CSS?

```
<ul class="post-categories">
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

PHP:

```
    <?php
        $relateds = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post', 
        'posts_per_page' => 10, 'cat' => the_category(), 'post__not_in' 
        => array(get_the_ID())));
        if ( $relateds->have_posts() ):
        while ( $relateds->have_posts() ): $relateds->the_post(); ?>

        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="media">
            <div class="d-flex align-self-start">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body pl-3">
                <div class="media-title">
                    <?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_title(), 15); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>

        <?php endwhile; else: endif;
        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    </aside><!-- /.blog-sidebar -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Current result is st like this:

- Category 1
- Category 2

  Post 1

  Post 2

  Post 3

  ...

But I want only:

```
Post 1

Post 2

Post 3
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove categories, just remove function **the_category()** of the variable **$relateds**, so to do this,
change:

```
$relateds = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'cat' => the_category(), 'post__not_in' => array(get_the_ID())));
```

to:

```
$relateds = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'post__not_in' => array(get_the_ID())));
```

Hope this help you!

Comment: Hi Jandeilson De Sousa, thanks for your answer
But I want the posts in the same category

Comment: Maybe I did not get it right... this category function is calling all categories, would you like to limit it to specific categories?

Comment: Yeah, the my loop is inside another loop of the current post and I just want to get a list of videos that are in the same category with the current one, no matter in which category they are because the current post maybe in many categories.

Comment: I think `'cat' => 0` instead `'cat' => the_category()` function can solve this problem.